# Pass non ascii characters in response headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to download file where in some file it contains non ascii characters, at this time download gets failed. It gives the below error.

> Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x000D

The code works well with ascii characters. I am passing the file name in response header to UI which is developed in angular 6.

Below is my code

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("someroute/downloadfile")]
        public IActionResult DownloadFile(int ID)
        {
            try
            {
                    using (ExcelPackage pck = bal.DownloadFile(ID))
                    {
                        System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                        {
                            FileName = pck.File.Name,
                        };

                        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

                        return File(pck.GetAsByteArray(), "application /vndopenxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

However, my requirement is I want to download the file as is though it has non ascii characters.

Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: A file name with 0x000D isn't a valid filename. fix that

Comment: Did you try Encoding?

Comment: @CalinVlasin Nope. thats what I am looking for.. Can you please help me on that ?

Comment: @Tseng Its the exception generated because of file name contains non ascii characters. I want to download with non ascii characters

Comment: Please refer to this: http://blog.softartisans.com/2013/06/03/how-to-download-files-containing-special-or-non-ascii-characters-in-the-filename-using-asp-net/ . There are a lot of references on stackoverflow about this.

Comment: btw. 0x000d is carriage return (similar to a new line, but historically different due to the way printers and electric typewriter did work)

Comment: Why not just use `return File(stream, "application /vndopenxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", pck.File.Name);` ???

Comment: @Tseng Yeah.. tried with that way.. But it converting non ascii characters to _ in downloaded file name. I want non ascii character in file name.

Comment: @XamDev: Non-ascii characters are not allowed there. Read the [RFC1806](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1806), it clearly states: __Current [RFC 1521] grammar restricts parameter values (and hence
   Content-Disposition filenames) to US-ASCII__. And again, **WHY** do you need a carriage return in a filename? operating systems generally don't support such names anyways

Comment: @Tseng Agree with you.. its customer requirement. I have created blank file on win 10 with non ascii characters which is getting created successfully.

Comment: @CalinVlasin Thanks for the reply. I have tried the code from the provided link. It works fine on IE but not on chrome, firefox. I have added the exact code. But it still gives error on chrome, firefox

Comment: The talk here is not about windows, its about HTTP and the underlying standards. Read the linked RFC which describes it. Content-Disposition isn't part of HTTP Standard (see [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-15.5)) itself but rather an extension to it, but other than RFC1806 (linked above or the updated linkes). Some browsers may treat it one way and others in other, no standard there. Also for carriage return, read [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) to understand what it is

Comment: @Tseng Thanks for the info.. So do you mean to say that what i am trying to do is not at all possible?

Comment: @XamDev: Didn't said its not possible, the linked post shows one implementaiton but not all implement it and you'll have issues with the compatibility. The only supported one which works everywhere is when you don't send any non US-ASCII characters, which is guaranteed to work everywhere (in browsers that support it). Everything else, could be considered a "hack" at best. You shouldn't blindly accept any requirement and make the decision maker aware of the technical limitations in this case. its a suggestion anyways, a browser can use it or ignore it, the user can change the name before saving

Comment: Also as the RFC mentions, its not 100% secure, invalid pathes could be passed (which transverse like ../../), or file being to long (imagine it being downloaded on a DOS based browser with 8 char limit for the file name), so every browser/client has to check it themselves

Comment: @Tseng I completely agree with you. But the problem is that they have seen this for other applications/links it can be done. So they now want it. Anyway the link provided by Calin Vlasin it only work for IE and not for other browsers. Still if you have any solution which will across browsers it will be helpful. Thanks a lot again for valuable info, which added to my knowledge certainly.

Answer (score 2):

You could encode the non-ASCII header text as Base64, for example `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dirtyString)))`.

In Angular you can use `atob` get the non-ASCII string back.